# Spring4D TObjectDataSet Arabic charactes in win 10

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I am using Sprinfg4D TObjectDataSet in a project, all is perfect in windows 7,  but wheen i move the application to windows 10 , the fields with arabic characters seem not woking correctly, in SqlSevrer DB all is perfect except the UI, specialy the arabic characters showed like ???????, even in DBGrid, even in DevExpress Controls.
[image]

SQLServer
[image]

Comment: You are using the same connection string?

Comment: If you are using the TObjectDataSet then you have objects that contain the strings from the database. The question is if you retrieve those properly. It certainly has nothing to do with the ODS.

Comment: But this working perfectly in Win7!

Comment: I don't care - I am telling you that it has to do with the retrieval of the data from the DB and not the ODS. Which you did not tell anything about. Put a breakpoint in your DB access code and check if values arrive properly. That's debugging 101.

Comment: Also FWIW does any other arabic text show properly in your application on Windows 10? If not then it might be some font missing -  see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3083806/why-does-some-text-display-with-square-boxes-in-some-apps-on-windows-1

Comment: @Stefan Glienke, All is Ok when i bind directelly to (BindingSource with ADOTable), All labels captions with arabic is ok(even in win10), but wheen, i use TObjectDataSet  connected   to a list of objects filled from data, it occure and only wheen i use Win10, in win7 all is ok. but Font i think, if the used Font not found , you will be switched to default one(i will see the link thank you).